# Always connected in Gmail Chat

Tags: google-talk

I tried to set my status to invisible in Gmail Chat, but I got "Oops! You are not invisible because you're logged into Google Talk from another client, device, or location that doesn't support invisibility." message.

I used the "Sign out all other sessions" button, log out from Google+ Hangouts and use the old Gmail Chat. Then logged out and turned off all my devices (web browser and tablet), and checked with a friend if I was connected, and I still was. Also removed access to all sites, apps and services, even unlinked my account from the tablet. But the problem persists.

How to really disconnect from the Gmail Chat?

Comment: You might want to make sure that none of the devices that you turned off and on have automatic startup or sign-in setup.

Comment: My tablet is off, and i don't have the gmail open in the browser.

Comment: Hmm...have you checked that you don't have Google Talk on auto-load when you startup your computer [see here](https://support.google.com/talk/answer/23915?hl=en)

Comment: Also, [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chat/T1jvgnRSemo) in the Google Chat product forum might be helpful- you're certainly not the only one who has had this problem!

Comment: I am sure, i don't use any client for instant messaging.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem recently. The short answer is: Now that Gtalk desktop client, GChat in Gmail, and different Gmail accounts are linked now via G+ and Hangouts, if you're signed in to any of these, on any PC, in any Google account, this problem can pop up.

Here's what I did to fix it:

1. Go into one of your gmail accounts where you use Gtalk
2. In the left sibebar, there is your picture icon and a little arrow, above where it says "Sign into chat"
3. If that arrow is green, then you're logged into Gtalk via Gmail. Log out there.
4. Then, log out of your desktop GTalk client. Make sure you sign out first, then exit the program second. Don't exit without signing out. Sign out, then exit program.
5. Go back to Gmail. A the bottom of the screen, lower right, there is a link that says "details"
6. When you click it, another window will open up. This window will tell you all the IP address locations where you're currently logged into a Gmail or google account.
7. If you're logged in on another machine or network, it won't say "You do not appear to be logged in anywhere else". If you are logged in somewhere else, it will say what my screenshot says: "You do not appear to be logged in elsewhere".
8. If you are logged in, just click the button to log out of everywhere.
9. Sign out of that Google account. Repeat the steps for all Google accounts you have. You'll be surprised how many instances of Google you may be logged into. I was.
10. Clear your browser cache. Then, clear your DNS cache: CMD -> ipconfig/flushdns in Windows.

You should be good to go then.

Comment: ADDENDUM: I've noticed also that it's not enough to just ext out of GTALK without signing out. You have to actually sign out in order to be logged off. Even if you exit the program but don't sign out, you're still signed in.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had some updates on my smartphone (Android) and after that I noticed the message **Oops! You are not invisible because you're logged into Google Talk from another client, device or location that doesn't support invisibility.** when I checked into my Gmail account on my laptop.

After trying out a number of actions as posted in this stream, I checked the Google Hangout app on my smartphone again and found out that I was logged on. After logging off the - Oops,... message - disappeared and I became invisible again.

Sometimes a solution can be simple ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following and check for it once

Login into your gmail account

[image]

as shown in pic you can view your account's last activity
[image]

Now clear all browser history and retry to check in with your gtalk

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.

I just changed my Gmail password by logging into a web browser on another computer and then logged off from that computer.

Within an hour or so, I was logged out of Google Talk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (open in another tab) the Google+ hangout (a.k.a. old GTalk), you will receive that message from within gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and the only thing that worked was to explicitly logout from the Hangouts Android app (via *Menu* → *Settings* → *Logout*) if you are using it of course!

Comment: How is this answer different than the existing ones?

Comment: Can you tell who said you have to explicitly log out from the hangout app ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and logging off on Hangouts on my Android phone didn't help nor any of the steps mentioned in this post. 
The steps mentioned in this link worked perfectly fine - http://karthikkn.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/fixed-the-always-online-problem-with-google-chat/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tried all the steps, switched off my phone, and I was still in the "Oops, ..." mode.

Not signed in anywhere else. Several tries at all the suggestions.  Still in "Oops, ..." mode.

Then I noticed that my Gmail setting above the "Oops, ..." said "Sign out of Chat". Clicked it & became 'invisible' again.

What a Muppet ....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I was unable to go invisible. I did try the signing out of all sessions but that still did not work. Finally, I signed out of Google Hangouts on my phone. So if you're signed into Google Hangouts on any other device with the same account you cannot go invisible.